# My CNN Keras doesn't predict properly and I don't know what to do

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have to do a CNN to diagnosis Diabetic retinopathy in 4th stage (binary classification - or 0 (non4thStage - nonPdr), or 1 (4thStage - pdr)) I'm using vgg16 and a gaussianBlur to better classification. I have 1400 test images (700 each class) and this is my train.py:

```py
#import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Reshape
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, ZeroPadding2D, Dropout
from keras import optimizers
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

TRAIN_DIR = 'train/'
TEST_DIR = 'test/'
v = 'v/'
BATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_EPOCHS = 5


def ReadImages(Path):
    LabelList = list()
    ImageCV = list()
    classes = ["nonPdr", "pdr"]

    # Get all subdirectories
    FolderList = [f for f in os.listdir(Path) if not f.startswith('.')]

    # Loop over each directory
    for File in FolderList:
        for index, Image in enumerate(os.listdir(os.path.join(Path, File))):
            # Convert the path into a file
            ImageCV.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image), (224,224)))
            LabelList.append(classes.index(os.path.splitext(File)[0])) 


            ImageCV[index] = cv2.addWeighted (ImageCV[index],4,cv2.GaussianBlur(ImageCV[index] , (0,0) , 10) ,-4 ,128)
    return ImageCV, LabelList


data, labels = ReadImages(TRAIN_DIR)
valid, vlabels = ReadImages(TEST_DIR)

vgg16_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=True)

# (2) remove the top layer
base_model = Model(input=vgg16_model.input, 
                   output=vgg16_model.get_layer("block5_pool").output)

# (3) attach a new top layer
base_out = base_model.output
base_out = Reshape((25088,))(base_out)
top_fc1 = Dense(64, activation="relu")(base_out)
top_fc1 = Dropout(0.50)(base_out)
# output layer: (None, 5)
top_preds = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(top_fc1)

# (4) freeze weights until the last but one convolution layer (block4_pool)
for layer in base_model.layers[0:14]:
    layer.trainable = False

# (5) create new hybrid model
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=top_preds)

# (6) compile and train the model
sgd = SGD(lr=0.000001, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

data = np.asarray(data)
valid = np.asarray(valid)

data = data.astype('float32')
valid = valid.astype('float32')

data /= 255
valid /= 255
labels = np.array(labels)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)
datagen.fit(data)
mean = datagen.mean  
std = datagen.std

print(mean, "mean")
print(std, "std")

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', verbose=1)

# fits the model on batches with real-time data augmentation:
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(data, np.array(labels), batch_size=32), 
                    steps_per_epoch=len(data) / 32, epochs=50,
                    validation_data=(valid, np.array(vlabels)),
                    nb_val_samples=72, callbacks=[es])


model.save('model.h5')
```

and this returns the follow:

```
Epoch 1/50
44/43 [==============================] - 475s 11s/step - loss: 0.9671 - acc: 0.4789 - val_loss: 0.6808 - val_acc: 0.6389
Epoch 2/50
44/43 [==============================] - 467s 11s/step - loss: 0.8427 - acc: 0.5007 - val_loss: 0.6364 - val_acc: 0.6389
Epoch 3/50
44/43 [==============================] - 468s 11s/step - loss: 0.7703 - acc: 0.5204 - val_loss: 0.6136 - val_acc: 0.6806
Epoch 4/50
44/43 [==============================] - 466s 11s/step - loss: 0.7324 - acc: 0.5512 - val_loss: 0.5941 - val_acc: 0.7500
Epoch 5/50
44/43 [==============================] - 466s 11s/step - loss: 0.7074 - acc: 0.5679 - val_loss: 0.5758 - val_acc: 0.7639
Epoch 6/50
44/43 [==============================] - 461s 10s/step - loss: 0.6640 - acc: 0.6146 - val_loss: 0.5584 - val_acc: 0.8194
Epoch 7/50
44/43 [==============================] - 455s 10s/step - loss: 0.6562 - acc: 0.6077 - val_loss: 0.5418 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 8/50
44/43 [==============================] - 458s 10s/step - loss: 0.6076 - acc: 0.6700 - val_loss: 0.5263 - val_acc: 0.8889
Epoch 9/50
44/43 [==============================] - 456s 10s/step - loss: 0.5743 - acc: 0.7005 - val_loss: 0.5119 - val_acc: 0.9167
Epoch 10/50
44/43 [==============================] - 457s 10s/step - loss: 0.5649 - acc: 0.7041 - val_loss: 0.4981 - val_acc: 0.9306
Epoch 11/50
44/43 [==============================] - 452s 10s/step - loss: 0.5654 - acc: 0.7088 - val_loss: 0.4855 - val_acc: 0.9444
Epoch 12/50
44/43 [==============================] - 458s 10s/step - loss: 0.5046 - acc: 0.7616 - val_loss: 0.4740 - val_acc: 0.9444
Epoch 13/50
44/43 [==============================] - 465s 11s/step - loss: 0.5002 - acc: 0.7808 - val_loss: 0.4633 - val_acc: 0.9444
Epoch 14/50
44/43 [==============================] - 459s 10s/step - loss: 0.4694 - acc: 0.7924 - val_loss: 0.4514 - val_acc: 0.9583
Epoch 15/50
44/43 [==============================] - 463s 11s/step - loss: 0.4482 - acc: 0.8184 - val_loss: 0.4432 - val_acc: 0.9444
Epoch 16/50
44/43 [==============================] - 456s 10s/step - loss: 0.4326 - acc: 0.8343 - val_loss: 0.4330 - val_acc: 0.9583
Epoch 17/50
44/43 [==============================] - 454s 10s/step - loss: 0.4291 - acc: 0.8303 - val_loss: 0.4233 - val_acc: 0.9583
Epoch 18/50
44/43 [==============================] - 457s 10s/step - loss: 0.4060 - acc: 0.8376 - val_loss: 0.4145 - val_acc: 0.9583
Epoch 19/50
44/43 [==============================] - 457s 10s/step - loss: 0.3933 - acc: 0.8686 - val_loss: 0.4069 - val_acc: 0.9583
Epoch 20/50
44/43 [==============================] - 455s 10s/step - loss: 0.3786 - acc: 0.8684 - val_loss: 0.3985 - val_acc: 0.9583
Epoch 21/50
44/43 [==============================] - 456s 10s/step - loss: 0.3661 - acc: 0.8774 - val_loss: 0.3902 - val_acc: 0.9583
Epoch 22/50
44/43 [==============================] - 454s 10s/step - loss: 0.3493 - acc: 0.8956 - val_loss: 0.3833 - val_acc: 0.9583
Epoch 23/50
44/43 [==============================] - 456s 10s/step - loss: 0.3355 - acc: 0.9065 - val_loss: 0.3765 - val_acc: 0.9444
Epoch 24/50
44/43 [==============================] - 456s 10s/step - loss: 0.3332 - acc: 0.9053 - val_loss: 0.3680 - val_acc: 0.9583
Epoch 25/50
44/43 [==============================] - 457s 10s/step - loss: 0.3236 - acc: 0.9160 - val_loss: 0.3625 - val_acc: 0.9444
Epoch 26/50
44/43 [==============================] - 458s 10s/step - loss: 0.3097 - acc: 0.9181 - val_loss: 0.3559 - val_acc: 0.9583
Epoch 27/50
44/43 [==============================] - 469s 11s/step - loss: 0.2915 - acc: 0.9242 - val_loss: 0.3517 - val_acc: 0.9444
Epoch 28/50
44/43 [==============================] - 473s 11s/step - loss: 0.2832 - acc: 0.9368 - val_loss: 0.3454 - val_acc: 0.9583
Epoch 29/50
44/43 [==============================] - 468s 11s/step - loss: 0.2747 - acc: 0.9418 - val_loss: 0.3416 - val_acc: 0.9583
Epoch 30/50
44/43 [==============================] - 470s 11s/step - loss: 0.2627 - acc: 0.9508 - val_loss: 0.3350 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 31/50
44/43 [==============================] - 469s 11s/step - loss: 0.2517 - acc: 0.9638 - val_loss: 0.3311 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 32/50
44/43 [==============================] - 470s 11s/step - loss: 0.2517 - acc: 0.9484 - val_loss: 0.3266 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 33/50
44/43 [==============================] - 490s 11s/step - loss: 0.2348 - acc: 0.9560 - val_loss: 0.3211 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 34/50
44/43 [==============================] - 461s 10s/step - loss: 0.2427 - acc: 0.9517 - val_loss: 0.3158 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 35/50
44/43 [==============================] - 467s 11s/step - loss: 0.2260 - acc: 0.9616 - val_loss: 0.3109 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 36/50
44/43 [==============================] - 459s 10s/step - loss: 0.2243 - acc: 0.9706 - val_loss: 0.3064 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 37/50
44/43 [==============================] - 456s 10s/step - loss: 0.2099 - acc: 0.9687 - val_loss: 0.3029 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 38/50
44/43 [==============================] - 457s 10s/step - loss: 0.2094 - acc: 0.9733 - val_loss: 0.2994 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 39/50
44/43 [==============================] - 465s 11s/step - loss: 0.2014 - acc: 0.9744 - val_loss: 0.2941 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 40/50
44/43 [==============================] - 465s 11s/step - loss: 0.1924 - acc: 0.9709 - val_loss: 0.2915 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 41/50
44/43 [==============================] - 457s 10s/step - loss: 0.1908 - acc: 0.9735 - val_loss: 0.2897 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 42/50
44/43 [==============================] - 463s 11s/step - loss: 0.1864 - acc: 0.9709 - val_loss: 0.2861 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 43/50
44/43 [==============================] - 464s 11s/step - loss: 0.1787 - acc: 0.9773 - val_loss: 0.2822 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 44/50
44/43 [==============================] - 468s 11s/step - loss: 0.1820 - acc: 0.9744 - val_loss: 0.2794 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 45/50
44/43 [==============================] - 469s 11s/step - loss: 0.1646 - acc: 0.9818 - val_loss: 0.2763 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 46/50
44/43 [==============================] - 469s 11s/step - loss: 0.1689 - acc: 0.9820 - val_loss: 0.2730 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 47/50
44/43 [==============================] - 471s 11s/step - loss: 0.1495 - acc: 0.9879 - val_loss: 0.2711 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 48/50
44/43 [==============================] - 469s 11s/step - loss: 0.1578 - acc: 0.9858 - val_loss: 0.2676 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 49/50
44/43 [==============================] - 462s 10s/step - loss: 0.1557 - acc: 0.9858 - val_loss: 0.2643 - val_acc: 0.9722
Epoch 50/50
44/43 [==============================] - 454s 10s/step - loss: 0.1501 - acc: 0.9794 - val_loss: 0.2612 - val_acc: 0.9722
```

This is my predict.py:

```py
from keras.models import load_model
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

TEST_DIR = 'v/'
pdr = 0
nonPdr = 0

model = load_model('model.h5')

def normalize(x, mean, std):
    x[..., 0] -= mean[0]
    x[..., 1] -= mean[1]
    x[..., 2] -= mean[2]
    x[..., 0] /= std[0]
    x[..., 1] /= std[1]
    x[..., 2] /= std[2]
    return x

for filename in os.listdir(r'v/'):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".ppm") or filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
        ImageCV = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join(TEST_DIR) + filename), (224,224))
        ImageCV = cv2.addWeighted (ImageCV,4,cv2.GaussianBlur(ImageCV , (0,0) , 10) ,-4 ,128)
        ImageCV = np.asarray(ImageCV)

        ImageCV = ImageCV.astype('float32')

        ImageCV /= 255  
        x = ImageCV

        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = normalize(x, [0.23883381, 0.23883381, 0.23883381], [0.24483591, 0.24579705, 0.2510857])

        prob = model.predict(x)
        if prob <= 0.75:  #.75 = 80% | .70=79% >>>> .70 = 82% | .75 = 79%
            print("nonPDR >>>", filename)
            nonPdr += 1
        else:
            print("PDR >>>", filename)
            pdr += 1
        print(prob)
print("Number of retinas with PDR: ",pdr)
print("Number of retinas without PDR: ",nonPdr)
```

The problem is: after the train returns about 97% of accuracy, all my predictions are wrong... for example, this 3 images must be PDR(class1):

```py
nonPDR >>> 16_left.jpeg
[[0.07062916]]
nonPDR >>> 16_right.jpeg
[[0.09434311]]
nonPDR >>> 217_left.jpeg
[[0.14126943]]
```

If I put to test the same images I put in train base, the model doesn't predict properly too...

I'd already tried to train without gaussianBlur but the accuracy was very poor.

What I'm doing wrong? Please, I appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to try:  I would suggest not using data augmentation until you have some confidence that your training process is working, even if the performance is not good initially.  As a double check, you might want to directly do prediction right after the model.fit, using the training data, just to verify that the resulting accuracy is the same as what you got in training.  You might have some small differences in the processing of the test data that is causing the network to behave poorly, so it would be a good first step to convince yourself that the training part is okay then you can focus on the test part.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I drop out the data augmentation, and my predictions still bad